# Relation between webserver port and http port

Tags: http, port

I need help understanding relation between port used by webserver and port used by http.

When we run a web server on port `XYZ`,then it means that there is a webserver running at `http://<IP>:XYZ` ,but we also say that `http` uses port `80` .

How are these two ports `XYZ` and `80` related ?

Answer (score 0):

When you set a non-default port number for a webserver, in this case XYZ instead of 80 (default port number for non-secure web hosts), you assign that XYZ port number to to the web server. I.e. the 80 port number does not apply to it anymore.